# How to delete an item in an array that is inside mongodb specific document?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have this collection in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5890e5ea619737392c257846"),
    "email" : "ewrt@ert.com",
    "pass" : "123456",
    "firstName" : "sdlriugth",
    "lastName" : "sdfligkjh",
    "movies" : [ 
        ObjectId("5890e5ec619737392c257847"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5ed619737392c257848"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5ee619737392c257849"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5ee619737392c25784a")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5890e5f8619737392c25784c"),
    "email" : "wieruy@dgf.com",
    "pass" : "123456",
    "firstName" : "yjhtgj",
    "lastName" : "vbnvbng",
    "movies" : [ 
        ObjectId("5890e5fa619737392c25784d"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5fb619737392c25784e"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5fc619737392c25784f")
    ]
}
```

There are 2 users, each user has an array of movies id's.

I want to do a query that will remove a specific movie Id from the user that has this movie.

let's say if I'll remove the movie id : "5890e5ee619737392c25784a" I will get:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5890e5ea619737392c257846"),
    "email" : "ewrt@ert.com",
    "pass" : "123456",
    "firstName" : "sdlriugth",
    "lastName" : "sdfligkjh",
    "movies" : [ 
        ObjectId("5890e5ec619737392c257847"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5ed619737392c257848"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5ee619737392c257849"), 
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5890e5f8619737392c25784c"),
    "email" : "wieruy@dgf.com",
    "pass" : "123456",
    "firstName" : "yjhtgj",
    "lastName" : "vbnvbng",
    "movies" : [ 
        ObjectId("5890e5fa619737392c25784d"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5fb619737392c25784e"), 
        ObjectId("5890e5fc619737392c25784f")
    ]
}
```

P.S
I what the changes to be made on all relevant documents. (many users can have the same movie id)

Thanks :)

Comment: I forgot to tell that I want the changes to be made on all relevant documents and not on specific user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $pull operator.
So in your case the query would be

```
db.collection.updateOne({"_id": ObjectId("5890e5ea619737392c257846")},
{"$pull": {"movies": ObjectId("5890e5ee619737392c25784a")}})
```